# Difference between t(:str) and t :str in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

i am new to ROR.. i am having a doubt in internationalization commands.

in some case we were using `<%=t :str_use%>`

and in some cases we were using  `<%= t(:str_use) %>`

what is the difference between these two

when should i have to use 1st and when to use the second one..

Pls give some ideas regarding this.

i am having a view file with in that i am having lot of strings i wanna to internationalization them.

in some cases i am having like `<td>Use</td>`

and in some cases

```
<% if use %> Use <br />
<% else %>
```

Comment: you mean difference between `t(:str)` and `t :str` (not `t: str`), right?

Comment: ya .. where to use t(:str) and where to use <%=t :str%>

Comment: It would be worth editing the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

This is ruby's syntax, not specifically ror ;)

Both are the same. Ruby can guess the parenthesis even if they're not there.
So it's completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between `t :str` and `t(:str)` — they both call the method `t` with the symbol `:str` as an argument. In Ruby, parentheses around arguments are optional.

But these are both different from `t: str`, which is Ruby 1.9 shorthand for the hash `{:t => str}`.

Answer (score 0):

When to use t(:str)? When you want to chain further methods.

Try this in Rails:

```
t 'some.translation'.capitalize
t('some.translation').capitalize
```

First approach will return:

```
Translation
```

..as in the second half the identifier after the period, instead of translating the whole text. This, from what I can tell, is because you are passing the argument `'some.translation'.capitalize`, not calling `capitalize` on the return, like the second example.